# Prolog: Trying to define a first cousin

Tags: prolog

I am doing a basic genealogy program and am having trouble in terms of only printing out the list once.

```
firstcousin(C,X) :-
   grandparent(G,X),
   grandparent(G,C),
   C\=X,
   \+sibiling(C,X).
```

It prints out the correct people, just it does the list twice. I know this has to do with grandparent because everyone has two grandparents. So basically it will look at one grandparent of both `X` and `C`, and then look at the other grandparent.  So, in summary, I just do not want the list of cousins to repeat.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are four ways of checking if someone is my cousin: we either share my mother's mother, my father's mother, my mother's father or my father's father. If any of these is true (and that person is not me or my sibling), then "someone" is my cousin. Prolog will try every option, so you could possibly have your cousin listed four times! You can check it out my making two sisters marry two brothers.

Another way to look it: there are two ways I can walk into the tree to find who are my cousins, and Prolog will try both. In the corner case, there are four ways to walk in the tree.

Anyways, in this specific problem a good way of dealing with this is not going two levels in the genealogy tree to check for cousin-hood. You could say that someone is my cousin if one of my parents is sibling to one of his parents. Note that this doesn't solve the corner case yet (there are now two ways instead of four), I will let it for you to try solving.

```
firstcousin(C, X) :- parent(C, O), parent(X, T), C \= X, sibling(O, T).
```

---

Another option of course is to write `firstcousins(C, X)` where X will be a list of all first-degree cousins of C, then you can check that a new element is not yet an element of the list. Variants include calculating the entire list then removing the duplicates. I find this method less elegant than a pure logical solution.

Comment: I do not have a Prolog environment at hand to test the provided code. If there is any error please let me know and I'll fix/remove it.

Comment: You can always use this online editor http://swish.swi-prolog.org/, I use it a lot

Comment: @Yasel thank you, I played a little in swish and fixed the code accordingly.